# Single MongoDB query to aggregate count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection `peopleColl` containing records with people data. Each record is uniquely indexed by id and has a `managers` field of type array.

Example:

```
{
   id: 123,
   managers: [456, 789]
},
{
   id: 321,
   managers: [555, 789]
}
```

I want to write a single query to find all people with the same manager, for several ids (managers). So given [456, 555, 789] the desired output would be:

```
{
    456: 1,
    555: 1,
    789: 2
}
```

I can do it (slowly) in a for-loop in Python as follows:

```
idToCount = {id: peopleColl.count({"managers": id}) for id in ids}
```

Edit: I am primarily interested in solutions <= MongoDB 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **3.4.4** and above

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$managers" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$managers", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": { "$toLower": "$_id" },
        "v": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }}}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "456": 1,
    "555": 1,
    "789": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: NB. ids are changed from int to string, however, this is a fast workable soln. ty

Answer (score 1):

You can try below pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$managers" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$managers", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}}
])
```

Output:

```
{'_id': 456, 'count': 1},
{'_id': 555, 'count': 1},
{'_id': 789, 'count': 2}
```

So you can loop through and create the Id-Count mapping

```
result = db.collection.aggregate([
      { "$unwind": "$managers" },
      { "$group": { "_id": "$managers", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}}
    ])

iD_Count = {}
result.forEach(function(d, i) {
iD_Count[d._id] = d.count;
})
```

iD_Count:

```
{
    456: 1,
    555: 1,
    789: 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation in 3.6.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$unwind":"$managers"},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$managers","count":{"$sum":1}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "managerandcount":{"$mergeObjects":{"$arrayToObject":[[["$_id","$count"]]]}}
  }},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$managerandcount"}}
])
```